# Lose Focus on Moving Next Text Field using Text Switcher

Tags: android

i m Using TextSwitcher to Move to Next Text Field Automatically it moves to the next Field perfectly 
but when cursor moves to the next field it still focus the Previous textfield 
Code for this is following

```
public void textWatcher(){

        pin.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            @Override

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, 

                            int count) {

                if(pin.getText().toString().length()==1)

                {


                    pin2.requestFocus();

                    pin.clearFocus();


                }

            }

            @Override

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,

                    int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            }

        });
}
```

Any Suggestion help will be greatful 
Regards 
Usman Kurd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void textWatcher(){
   pPin1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
      int after) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     if(pPin1.getText().toString().length()==1)
     {
      pPin2.requestFocus();
     }
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

   });
}
```

Please try this code.. It will work perfect.

Answer (score 2):

please use

pin2.setFocusable(true);

then it will work perfectly.

please try

Comment: Actually my text Field is Password Type So it is Not working With SetFocusable also i`ve already tried it an also clearfocus() too

Comment: please set pin1 max character limit in xml. So that it would not write anymore in pin1 and move to pin2.

Comment: all prerequisites are performed i`ve already took care of this in XML @ Umer Abid